# ArrayAdapter Error

Tags: android-layout, listview, custom-adapter

Hi I am trying to implement a custom adapter. I have been getting the following error:

```
03-16 05:23:22.003: E/AndroidRuntime(316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 05:23:22.003: E/AndroidRuntime(316): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

This is how I try to populate my ListView:

```
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
```

which is where I get the error.

I have seen a lot of answers online that say you need to pass in a TextView, but I want each row to have an image along with two TextViews. I was following this tutorial, http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ and their custom layout works fine, it doesn't complain. I am using the same custom layout that they use in the tutorial for each row. Why is my complaining

Answer (score 0):

check below one in your code

`public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>`

Have you written RowItem? It may be possibility that you forget to change `ArrayAdapter<String>` to `ArrayAdapter<RowItem>`